# Discord.py How can message be saved and visible in code?

Tags: python, discord, save

I have been making discord bot for me and my friends for some time.
I'd like to make them able to add some messages to table by using command save on channels.
I've already made it, but table is getting empty after every bot restart.
How can message be saved and visible in code ?

that's the part of my code im telling about

```
table = [

]

@bot.command()
async def save(ctx):
    a = ctx.message.content.replace('.save','')
    table.append(a)
    await ctx.message.channel.send('saved')
```

Answer (score 0):

`table` is a variable in RAM. It will be cleared, once you restart the bot. To save messages beyond restarting your bot, you will need to save them to your harddrive.
You can use

```
with open("saved_messages.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(a)
```

This will append every message to `saved_messages.txt`. You will need to load this file from your harddrive everytime you start your bot

```
saved_messages = open('saved_messages.txt', 'r')
Lines = saved_messages.readlines()
 
for line in Lines:
    table.append(line)
```